# binding a keypress event to a label widget tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I´m trying to bind the event click1 to self.entrada4_2 (which is a label), it does not work no matter what I try.

```
class Pagina_dos(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        texto4_1=tk.Label(self, text="Registro") .grid(row=0, column=0)
        texto4_2=tk.Label(self, text="Peso") .grid(row=1, column=0)
        entrada4_1=tk.Label(self, width=20, text=1)
        entrada4_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entrada4_2=ttk.Label(self,text="", width=20)
        self.update_pesa()
        def click1 (event=None):
            global numero_registro
            agarre=self.entrada4_2.cget("text")
            lista_regsitro.append(agarre)
            numero_registro=numero_registro+1
            entrada4_1=tk.Label(self, width=20, text=numero_registro)
            entrada4_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entrada4_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        boton_registrar=tk.Button(self)
        self.entrada4_2.bind('<Return>', click1)
        boton_registrar.config(text="REGISTRAR",width=11, command=click1)
        boton_registrar.grid(row=2, column=0)
        boton_acabar=tk.Button(self, text="PARAR",width=7, command=controller.destruir).grid(row=2, column=1)
    def update_pesa(self):
        read=None
        ser=serial.Serial("COM4",baudrate=9600)
        while read==None:
            Pesa=ser.read()
            if Pesa==b"=":
                read=ser.read(7)
                self.entrada4_2.configure(text=read)
                self.after(100, self.update_pesa)
```

when I execute the code the key press does not work, but the button does work. Is there a way to bind the event to the label, or to bind a key press to a button?

Comment: What is the real goal? Since the label doesn't have focus, it will never see any keyboard events. You can give the label focus, but I doubt that's what you really want to do. Why do you need to give the label or button focus? Are you just trying to set it up so that if the user presses `<Return>` it clicks the default button? Also, does that frame appear in the root window, or in a `Toplevel`?

Comment: the frame apperas in Toplevel, and yes, i want to set it up so that if the user presses <Return> it clicks the default button, or that if the user presses <Return>, the function click1 activates.

Answer (score 0):

Since the goal is to have pressing the return key do the default action, the simplest solution is to bind to the toplevel itself. You then need to give the focus to the window when you open. It might happen by default depending on the OS, but it's good to be explicit about it.

Note: when you bind to a `Toplevel`, all of the widgets within that `Toplevel` also get the binding, so no matter what inner widget has the focus, the binding will work.

Comment: thank you, it finally worked binding the function to the frame